# return selected item value from a select element as a parameter in onchange event

Tags: html, razor

I'm trying to pass the selected item value as a string from a select drop down to some razor code within an onchange event with very little joy thus far.

```
<div class="sortby">
    Sort by:
    <select id="sortbyselect" onchange ="@HelperAccess.AnalyticsHelper.PostEvent("Sort by selection", "selection", this.value)">
        <option value="Recommended">Recommended</option>
        <option value="PriceHigh">Price: high to low</option>
        <option value="PriceLow">Price: low to high</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In the code above I would like to pass the result of the selection to the third paramenter (where it currently says 'this.value').

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your cannot call a server method like that. Your c# code will be executed in server and your `onchange` event executes on the client. Client(browser) cannot execute the C# method(`HelperAccess.AnalyticsHelper.PostEvent`).

What you can do is, make an ajax call to the server where you have action method to accept the value of the selected option and inside that call the relevant method you need and return whatever data you like to.

```
<select id="sortbyselect">
    <option value="Recommended">Recommended</option>
    <option value="PriceHigh">Price: high to low</option>
    <option value="PriceLow">Price: low to high</option>
</select>
```

and listen to the change event on this

```
$(function(){
   $("#sortbyselect").change(function(){
      $.get("MySort","Home",{ id:$(this).val()},function(res){
        //do something with the response
      });
   });    
});
```

Assuming you have an action method called MySort in HomeController

```
public ActionResult MySort(string id)
{
  // Call your c# helper method here and return something
}
```